# What is a context safe way to call functions within module.exports?

Tags: javascript, node.js, this

I have this in my JS file:

```
module.exports.function1() {};

module.exports.function2() { this.function1(); };

module.exports.function3() { module.exports.function1(); };
```

Which is the preferred way to invoke other functions from `module.exports` - `function2()` or `function3()` way? Or is there a better way?

I don't like `function2()` way because it's not context safe and `function3()` way looks kinda weird to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I prefer to declare the exports up top and then put the declarations below

```
module.exports = { 
    function1: function1, 
    function2: function2,
    function3: function3
}
function function1() { }
function function2() { function1(); }
function function3() { function1(); }
```

**Edit** I do it this way so that the function declarations can reference each other without having to go through `module.exports` or anything. Since it's in a module, it's self contained. Also, when you open the file, you get a clear look at the exports without having to wade through all the implementation first.

Comment: No explanation why? It would seem the OP wants more than just a: 'do it like this, kind of answer

Comment: is `function1()` actually referring to `module.exports.function1()` in this case? And not `this.function1()`?

Comment: I do the same, the other way around. With the exports at the bottom of the file.
And I use variables actually, so it's more like `var a = function(){}`. But that's not really different.

Comment: @potato300 `function2` and `function3` call `function1` directly. It does not need to use `this` to do so. `module.exports.function1` is equal to `function1`

Comment: @Vadorequest I used to put it at the bottom too, but I found myself doing more scrolling that way. Also, [John Papa's Angular styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#modules) recommends putting (Angular) definitions at the top

Comment: I actually never thought of it but I think that's indeed better. :)